# How to load entities of which a property of type PersistentList contains one or more values from array parameter?

Tags: codefluent

My model contain the following enumeration and entity:

```
<cf:enumeration name="Language" usePersistenceDefaultValue="false">
  <cf:enumerationValue name="EN" value="1" default="true" />
  <cf:enumerationValue name="NL" value="2" />
  <cf:enumerationValue name="DE" value="3" />
</cf:enumeration>

<cf:entity name="Person"  >
  <cf:property name="Id" key="true" />

  <cf:property name="Languages" typeName="CodeFluent.Runtime.Utilities.PersistentList&lt;Language&gt;">
    <cf:message class="_doc">The languages that the person speaks</cf:message>
  </cf:property>

  <cf:method name="LoadPersonThatSpeaksOneOrMoreLanguages" checkLevel="None" memberAttributes="Public" >
    <cf:body language="tsql" text="load(Language[] languages) from Person where Languages in (@languages)" />
  </cf:method>
</cf:entity>
```

The method LoadPersonThatSpeaksOneOrMoreLanguages should return all persons that speak one or more of the provided languages.
The generated stored procedure for this method seems not to be correct:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Person_LoadPersonThatSpeaksOneOrMoreLanguages]
(

 @languages [dbo].[cf_type_Person_LoadPersonThatSpeaksOneOrMoreLanguages_0] READONLY,
 @_orderBy0 [nvarchar] (64) = NULL,
 @_orderByDirection0 [bit] = 0
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @_c_languages int; SELECT @_c_languages= COUNT(*) FROM @languages
SELECT DISTINCT [Person].[Person_Id], ... 
    FROM [Person] 
    WHERE [Person].[Person_Languages] IN (((SELECT * FROM @languages)))
```

Question 1:
How can I achieve the desired result?
Should I create a Language entity and specify an 1:n association between Person and Language? I prefer not to have a Language entity.
Or can I specify that the Languages property must be converted to the same type as the table-valued-parameter (`cf_type_Person_LoadPersonThatSpeaksOneOrMoreLanguages_0`)?

Question 2:
The produced `PersonCollection` class contains the method `LoadPersonThatSpeaksOneOrMoreLanguages`. The parameter of this method is of type `Language[]`. Instead of an array I want an `IEnumerable<Language>`. How can I specify this in my XML model?

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1**

The `PersistentList` is designed to store a collection of simple values (int, string, enum, ...), but not to query them directly in SQL. Indeed the `PersistentList` is translated to a `NVARCHAR` column in the database and this column contains values like `EN|NL` (pipe separated values). The database engine does not know how to extract single values from the string. Maybe you can use the `cf_SplitString` function to create a table from the column value and do what you want with it, but it does not seem to be the simplest solution...

Depending of your need you can use a multi-valued enumeration:

```
<cf:enumeration name="Language" flags="true">
    <cf:enumerationValue name="Unspecified" /> <!-- value=0 -->
    <cf:enumerationValue name="EN" />          <!-- value=1 -->
    <cf:enumerationValue name="NL" />          <!-- value=2 -->
    <cf:enumerationValue name="FR" />          <!-- value=4 -->
</cf:enumeration>
```

You can use them with `CFQL`:

```
-- Load Persons that speak the specified language
LOAD(Languages) WHERE (Languages & @Languages) = @Languages

-- Load Persons that speak at least one of the specified language
LOAD(Languages) WHERE (Languages & @Languages) <> 0
```

Of course the latest possibilities is to create a Language entity and use Table Valued Parameters.

http://blog.codefluententities.com/2014/07/16/persistent-list/
http://www.softfluent.com/documentation/Enumerations_Overview.html

**Question 2**

From the [official blog](http://blog.codefluententities.com/2015/07/17/table-valued-parameters-use-ienumerable-instead-of-an-array/) of CodeFluent Entities:

[image]
[image]

Comment: So the values of my Language enumeration must be increasing powers of 2 (starting with 1) and instead of an array the languages parameter must contain the languages combined with the OR logical operator? That is a good idea!

Comment: That's the idea. CodeFluent Entities automatically set the value of the enumeration values. You just have to set `flags` to `true` so it will use powers of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Take what I say with a grain of salt as you are dealing with a topic I have looked into but never implemented. With that said another approach would be to use a multi-valued enumeration (flag)

http://blog.codefluententities.com/2013/05/29/using-flags-enumeration-with-aspnet-mvc-and-codefluent-entities

Using this approach you would create a relationship between the entity and the enumeration instead of making the Languages property a persistent list.

The following mostly works. When using the Modeler to create instances I was not able to select certain combinations of languages. Don't know if this was due to my inexperience in working with and setting up flag enumeration or if there is a flaw in the modeler. But I did manage to create the method and that part appears to be working.

```
<cf:enumeration name="Language" multivalue="true" usePersistenceDefaultValue="false" namespace="Demo1" categoryPath="/Demo1">
<cf:enumerationValue name="Unspecified" default="true" />
<cf:enumerationValue name="EN" />
<cf:enumerationValue name="NL" />
<cf:enumerationValue name="DE" />
</cf:enumeration>
<cf:entity name="Person" namespace="Demo1">
<cf:property name="Id" key="true" />
<cf:property name="Languages" usePersistenceDefaultValue="false" typeName="{0}.Language" />
<cf:property name="FirstName" />
<cf:property name="LastName" />
<cf:instance>
  <cf:instanceValue name="Id">d13447c6-a709-4c87-891d-e83674821915</cf:instanceValue>
  <cf:instanceValue name="FirstName">Jon</cf:instanceValue>
  <cf:instanceValue name="LastName">Smith</cf:instanceValue>
</cf:instance>
<cf:instance>
  <cf:instanceValue name="Id">77e3730c-2cc3-457d-8bc0-d9a5e224b96a</cf:instanceValue>
  <cf:instanceValue name="FirstName">Sam</cf:instanceValue>
  <cf:instanceValue name="Languages">DE, SP</cf:instanceValue>
  <cf:instanceValue name="LastName">Newman</cf:instanceValue>
</cf:instance>
<cf:method name="LoadPersonThatSpeaksOneOrMoreLanguages" body="LOAD() WHERE Languages &gt; 0" />
```

As I said take what I'm saying with a grain of salt. I ended up using an entity instead of an enumeration but only because that was what I was more familar with and had a deadline.

Comment: You should add an `None`/`Unspecified`/`Unknown` value in the enumeration with the value `0`. In your case the value of `EN` is `0` and cannot be used in a combination. Maybe this explain why you cannot create a instance with certain combinations of languages in the modeler.

Comment: I updated the enumeration in my code sample to include Unspecified. Thanks meziantou!